# Sublime text 3 plugin Bracket highlighter not working correctly

Tags: html, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

When i paste code inside a document, it's stops highlighting brackets of all document  and shows question mark near all div elements..

[image: Sublime text 3 Brackets Highlighting]

How can i solve this problem?

Before, it's highlighting open and closed tag
[image]

After pasting code inside , its showing question mark for all document..

Comment: Please show "before" and "after" images, and describe the problem more clearly. As it stands, I have no idea what your problem even is.

Comment: @ MattDMo added more details

Comment: To prevent this in the future, I urge you to create a complete set of tags before adding attributes or values to them. "Finish what you started." It's a fine habit to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this issue is because you have improperly nested tags in the `<header>` section. Your code is as follows:

```html
    <a href="#"><h1 class="title">Document</a><a href="#!/about-us" id="show-about-btn">▼</a></h1>
<!--open a      open h1                 close a|open a                               close a|close h1-->
```

or, in a condensed version:

```html
<a><h1></a><a></a></h1>
```

You can fix this by switching the first `<a>` and the `<h1>`:

```html
<h1 class="title">
    <a href="#">Document</a>
    <a href="#!/about-us" id="show-about-btn">▼</a>
</h1>
```

Everything is now properly nested, and the bracket highlighting will work as expected:

[image]